# How to release for multiple ROS versions when version dependent patches are needed?

Tags: ros, ros-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

due to the recent change in Bullet[1], I have to patch my stack when releasing for unstable
but not when releasing for Electric. The SCM I use for this stack is Git.

Then problem is that even if `create.py` maintains different branches for each ROS version (unstable and electric in my case), it always *update* them using the current state of the master branch.

What I would like to do in this case is *comitting myself* on unstable to handle [1]. Then I would like `create.py` to use the current state of the unstable branch to create the release.

Is it possible to do so? Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

[1] [ros-users Bullet change in unstable for Fuerte](http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Bullet-change-in-unstable-for-Fuerte-EFFECTS-ALL-PACAKGES-USING-Bullet-and-tf-td3544196.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12208/how-to-release-for-multiple-ros-versions-when-version-dependent-patches-are-needed?/) by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4478 on 2011-12-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The create.py updates the branch defined in the rosdistro file.  If you change the definition in the rosdistro file for each release it will pull from a different branch for the specified release.

For example in electric.rosdistro define the dev-branch to be electric-devel and the unstable.rosdistro file define the dev-branch to be master, etc.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-04-10**:
While releasing from a different branch for each distro is the "standard" ROS solution, that is not what external groups like ours want. We need our development trunk to work with two successive distros. Generally, tick-tock makes that possible, though it often means slower adoption of new features.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Partial answer**:

I had a similar problem for `geographic_info`. While I strongly prefer to maintain support for both distributions in a single source tree, ROS does not make that easy.

In my case, the cleanest solution was to drop the direct dependency on `bullet`, and use the equivalent `tf` types instead. That may not work for everyone.

If the `tf` types do not meet your needs, it might help for your C++ code to [query the ROS version using pre-processor tests](http://answers.ros.org/question/540/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c-code). Unfortunately, I know of no way to hide the `bullet` dependency differences in `manifest.xml`. As a tick-tock measure, maybe we should keep an empty `bullet` package around for Fuerte with just a `rosdep` for the system library.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-07**:
Well, I guess that's why we call it "unstable". :-)

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2011-12-06**:
I just noticed that unfortunately this version number is currently broken in unstable, see https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3782

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2011-12-05**:
Thanks, this is an interesting workaround, I will try that :)